# In Rails, how can I include a style sheet from the asset pipeline as a <style> tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4

Everyone knows how to use `stylesheet_link_tag` to *link* to a stylesheet, but I would like to actually include an entire stylesheet in a page itself. (No, this is normally not a great practice, but it makes sense in this context.)

`stylesheet_include_tag` does not exist, and a co-worker who is a much bigger bad-ass at Rails than I am says there isn’t a simple way.

**Question:**
Is it actually possible to make use of the asset pipeline *and* still embed the contents of a CSS or JavaScript file (compiled from Sass or CoffeeScript!) into a `.haml` view? How?

---

**Added** for clarity:

I’d like for my layout to be able to include something like:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "base"
= stylesheet_embed_tag "page-specific-styles/foo"
```

And have this generate output HTML along these lines:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/base.css" />
<style type="text/css">.foo { color: red; }</style>
```

---

**Update**

It’s possible to use Sass within Haml if you [set your initalizer correctly](https://gist.github.com/alanhogan/6290026), but I cannot seem to `@import "foo"` from this context, where `foo.css.sass` is a stylesheet in the asset pipeline. Note that `@import "compass"` (assuming you have the compass gem) does work.

This looks like (haml):

```
%style
  :sass
    @import "foo"
```

Rails gives an error that "foo" cannot be found, even though it claims to be looking in `app/assets/stylesheets` (which is where `foo.css.sass` lives).

So, this feels closer, but still not quite there.

Comment: If i understand correctly you want to include the actual CSS into the `.haml` view.

Comment: @David Yes. I will extend the question to make this explicit.

Comment: would you not consider maybe using the `content_for :head` block maybe or I think you could explicitly call it like `<%= stlyesheet_include_tag 'some_stylesheet' %>` but i mean as it is `.haml` I believe you wouldn't have the embedded ruby tags making it just `=stylesheet_include_tag 'some_stylesheet` I may be wrong. But there's two methods that I have suggested there two you. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: H from your edit I do thoroughly believe you may want to use rails layout content_for block - http://railscasts.com/episodes/8-layouts-and-content-for and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method

Comment: You really must have a special case, for using such a workaround :-). But anyway, I would do it like @sameera207 already said.

Answer (score 4):

from http://blog.phusion.nl/2011/08/14/rendering-rails-3-1-assets-to-string/ :

`YourApp::Application.assets.find_asset('api.css').source`

in haml

```
%style
    =raw YourApp::Application.assets.find_asset('foo.css').source
```

caveats:

I believe this requires asset compilation in production, which can be pretty costly.

Comment: Awesome! And no doubt some caching could totally eliminate that performance overhead

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could add your CSS code to a normal Ruby view file (as a partial), say `styles.html.erb`.

And then add that to your page upon any condition you want, I think it's the simplest way of looking at it.

Comment: Right, that occurred to me, too, and it would be the simplest, but **only if** I don’t need to use Sass features like extending other Sass files, as I understand it.

Comment: And as far as code re-use goes, obviously this is not going to cut it.